# How to filter date range with primefaces calendar?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I filter columns in data table with prime faces dataTable showcase example

```xml
<p:column id="logStatus" filterBy="#{log.status}" headerText="status">
    <h:outputText value="#{log.status}" />
</p:column>
<p:column filterBy="#{log.mbr}" headerText="mbr">
    <h:outputText value="#{log.mbr}" />
</p:column>
```

Everything works fine when the key is released filters are sent to my DAO where I do some logic.
I don't know how to implement this with `<p:calendar>`
I want to pick dates from calendar and sand it to DAO in the same way as it works with filters I provided above

A column with calendar, I need two calendars in one column

```xml
<p:column filterBy="#{log.datumOd}" headerText="datumupisa od">             
    <f:facet name="filter">
            <p:calendar id="datumOd" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy">
                    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" />
            </p:calendar>                   
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="filter">
            <p:calendar id="datumDo" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy">
                    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" />
            </p:calendar>                   
    </f:facet>              
    <h:outputText value="#{log.datumUpisa}" />
</p:column>
```

I need explanation how filterBy works? Should i use update, on complete and event ? I tried to use two columns and filterby dateFrom and dateTo, but events not working. It works if i pick dates and then filter by other filters ( from above ).
I will proivde more info and code if needed.

Comment: You need to invoke the JavaScript `filter()` method of the data table on change lik done in the  [showcase examples](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml).

Comment: In order to use range selection, the [datepicker](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/datePicker.xhtml) is worth a try.

Comment: I have dateFrom and dateTo in my bean so i think i need to put somewhere both filterBy="#{log.dateFrom}" and  filterBy="#{log.dateTo}" but i only have one column (its required to be in a single column)

Comment: I'm not sure if it's natively possible to filter a single column by two input components - this is why I suggested datepicker.

Comment: I splited it into two columns and used oncomplete="PF('loggerTable').filter()" and it works that way. Thank you